# Does the IDF claim that the Hamas tunnel(s?) under al-Shifa were not in use for a month or so before the IDF entered them?

Tags: 2023-israel-hamas-war, geneva-convention

There's a [video](https://youtu.be/8NqPgTcrCQg?t=128) posted by the IDF in which they seem to say that Hamas *sealed* the tunnels under Al-Shifa about a month before the IDF reached them.

So, what does that mean, more exactly? That Hamas had tunnel infrastructure under Al-Shifa but that they had *not used* it for a month or so before the IDF unsealed them?

Comment: Any reasons for the DVs?

Comment: Isn't this tunnel the same one that according to [Ehud Barak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVG7duZ-u2U) was built by Israel years ago?

Comment: @C.F.G: No, the IDF claims the one shown is "Hamas architecture", if you watch the whole clip. They discuss that around 6:15.

Comment: @C.F.G: Sky has diagram of there is located, apparently under the "Qatari building" of the hospital, which by the name I assume it's not one of the buildings from the Israeli occupation time.